# How to check if a file is in a dir and then delete it and another file?

Tags: bash

I'm now using Ubuntu, and increasingly using terminal.
I would like to delete files from Trash via command line.
So, I've gotta delete files from `~/.local/share/Trash/files` dir.

All right, here's the question:

When I move some file to trash, it also creates a `file_name.trashinfo` file in `~/.local/share/Trash/info`.
How could I automatically delete the corresponding `.trashinfo` file when I delete something in `../files`?

Comment: write a function that "wraps" you delete with additional logic to generate the `.trashinfo` filename(s) that you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to delete both files simultaneously. Save it in some file in the `~/.local/share/Trash` directory, and call then `bash <script.sh> <path-to-file-to-be-deleted-in-files-dir>`.

A sample call to delete the file `test` if you named the script `del.sh`: `bash del.sh files/test`

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                 

file=$1
if [ -e "$file" ] # check if file exists
then
  rm -rf "$file" # remove file
  base=$(basename "$file")
  rm -rf "info/$base.trashinfo" # remove second file in info/<file>.trashinfo

  echo 'files deleted!'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It runned fine!